# I have to refresh my php page after form submission to execute the code and display output

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, forms

Form Submission Code

```
<form action="search.php" method="POST" id="form2">
  <input type="text" name="Sr_no" required="true" placeholder="Enter Serial Number"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Check Status" name="ss">
</form>
```

My search.php

```
<?php

    $connect=mysqli_connect("localhost","root", "" ,"mydatabase");
    $Sr_no = $_POST["Sr_no"];

    $status_check = "SELECT verified FROM r_concession_forms WHERE id = '$Sr_id' LIMIT 1";
    $s_check = $connect->query($status_check);
    $s_value = $row = $s_check->fetch_assoc();

    if($s_value["verified"] == "0")
    {
        echo "<script>
            alert('Not Issued/Verified');
            window.location.href='index.php';
        </script>" ;
    }
    elseif($s_value["verified"] == "1"){
        echo "<script>
            alert('Issued and Verified');
            window.location.href='index.php';
            </script>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<script>
            alert('No Such Form Exists');
            window.location.href='index.php';
        </script>";
    }
?>
```

Output:
My Input first to check if that "id" exists in database

[image: Input on first page]

There is no alert box as expected, but the URL shows search.php, but no alert box displayed

[image: No alert box]

After refreshing the page, the alert box starts working

[image: After refresh it works]

The designing of page is by JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using a variable $Sr_id in the query which is not defined earlier. Also first check if the form is posted or not.

The code working fine when you refresh the page because, when you refresh the page there is no post data, so the query return empty value and it show "No such form exist". But when you post the page, the post value you given in query is wrong i guess.

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['ss'])) {
    $connect=mysqli_connect("localhost","root", "" ,"mydatabase");
    if(!empty($_POST['Sr_no'])) {
        $Sr_no = $_POST["Sr_no"];

        $status_check = 'select verified FROM r_concession_forms WHERE id = '.$Sr_no.' LIMIT 1';
        $s_check = $connect->query($status_check);
        $s_value = $row = $s_check->fetch_assoc();

        if($s_value["verified"] == "0")
        {
            echo "<script>
                alert('Not Issued/Verified');
                window.location.href='index.php';
            </script>" ;
        }
        elseif($s_value["verified"] == "1"){
            echo "<script>
                alert('Issued and Verified');
                window.location.href='index.php';
                </script>";
        }
        else{
            echo "<script>
                alert('No Such Form Exists');
                window.location.href='index.php';
            </script>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Also i personally don't prefer to use Script code inbetween PHP as you mentioned. Try to seperate the codes for better understanding.

Comment: Yes, thanks for your input i will keep them in mind. I just pointed out the reason for his issue. I haven't modified anything else in his code. i will update the reply now as you mentioned.